# AlpineJS: Conditionally add/remove attribute name?

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I've got a table where certain columns/cells are displayed or hidden based on a switcher using the Alpine :class directive:

`<td :class="{'invisible': viewSwitcher.activeType !== 'production'}">Cell Content</td>`

These cells are also exportable using jQuery plugin which provides a `removeExport` attribute that can be added to an element so that the exporter ignores it.

When a column/cell is hidden, I'd like to add the `removeExport` attribute to the element so that it isn't exported.

I know that I can do this with vanilla Javascript but I was wondering if it was possible to this with Alpine in a cleaner, more streamlined manner similar to how `x-bind` can dynamically add/remove attribute values?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given the plugin name and *"provides a removeExport attribute that can be added to an element so that the exporter ignores it"* seems a bit unusual.

To toggle an attribute with Alpine you can *x-bind* it and assign a *false* value to it if you don't what that attribute (in the following example I use the shorthand notation for x-bind):

```html
<td :removeExport = "viewSwitcher.activeType !== 'production'" :class="{'invisible': viewSwitcher.activeType !== 'production'}>
```

At this point can be useful adding a function in the x-data, that returns *true* if we are not in *production* (*<root-tag>* is the tag where you defined *x-data*):

```html
<root-tag x-data="{viewSwitcher: {activeType: 'production'}, isNotProduction: function() { return this.viewSwitcher.activeType !== 'production';} }">
```

and then in your <td>:

```html
<td :removeExport="isNotProduction()" :class="{'invisible': isNotProduction()}">
```